# Simple truly random number generator

Tags: random, von-neumann

There is a lot of research going on related to generating "truly" random numbers.

There is a very simple method, invented long time ago.
The method is attributed to von Neumann [[1]](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/algorithm-alley-unbiasing-random-bits/184405028).

In the most simple form it can be thought of as generating random bits out of a biased source of 0s or 1s. Given that probability of a sequence 01 is the same as 10, one can use 01 - to represent the truly random "0" and 10 as a truly random "1" bit (the 00 and 11 combinations are simply discarded).

Pretty straightforward. Can anyone point why such a method doesn't generate a random sequence (and thus solve the problem of generating random numbers on computers)?

Comment: Aside from the fact that it's no more random than the stream of bits that's being transformed? If I feed it "0110011001100110...." to get "010101....", which is no more (or less) random than the original sequence... That algorithm is about removing bias from a random sequence, not generating a random sequence in itself...

Comment: Isn't removing the bias from the random sequence equivalent to generating a random sequence? I.e. if each bit is random isn't the sequence random as well?

Comment: No. Assume that your RNG is generating uniform random numbers in `[0, 1]`. If it returned 0.5 all the time, it would have no bias, but still not be very random. *Better* PRNG's will give you unbiased, seemingly random sequences, but when you apply a suitable transformation to the random number sequence (such as plotting pairs of consecutive numbers in a 2D plane), distinct patterns will show up. Lastly there's the problem that eventually every PRNG will start to repeat itself after a (potentially very long) period.

Comment: @MichaelWild the example with 0.5 you provide is not valid because it is completely deterministic, i.e. the probability that in a certain position there will be a bit of "1" or "0" is 1. I was saying about biased source, i.e. the probability of bit "a0" is somewhat higher than probability of bit "not a0". Since the randomness doesn't guarantee that you will have bit a0 always in odd positions (i.e. 11.11.11.01.11.11.11) thus yielding only sequences of "truly random" zeros (0000...) you obtain a random sequence in the end.

Comment: @MichaelWild The problem of repeating sequences after some time is not a problem i think. For example given a domain output 1..N, in each N-size sequence you have each of the numbers to repeat exactly once (to qualify as truly random). After N! sequences you will repeat yourself even in a truly random scenario. Otherwise you are a priori biased (e.g. if in a sequence of N numbers some number appears twice) !

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain what "random" and "truly random" mean.  "Random" simply means the numbers are *identically distributed* and chosen *independently* of everything else (that is, the numbers are i.i.d.).  And "truly random" simply means i.i.d. and uniform (see also Frauchiger et al. 2013.)

If the source of input bits are i.i.d. but have a bias, then the von Neumann method will remove this bias — the numbers remain i.i.d. but are now unbiased, namely, each number will be 0 or 1 with equal probability.  In general, if the source numbers weren't i.i.d. (more specifically, *exchangeable* [Peres 1992]) to begin with, the von Neumann method won't make those numbers "truly random"; even von Neumann (1951) assumes "independence of successive tosses [of the coin]".  The von Neumann method is one of a host of randomness extractors available (and I discuss [some of them](https://peteroupc.github.io/randextract.html)), and this discussion applies to these other extractors just as well as the von Neumann method.

In any case, the distinction between "pseudorandom" and "truly random" numbers is not what applications care about (and you didn't really specify what kind of application you have in mind). Instead, in general:

- Security applications care whether the numbers are hard to guess; in this case, only a cryptographic RNG can achieve this requirement (even one that relies on a pseudorandom number generator). A Python example is the `secrets` module or `random.SystemRandom`.
- Scientific simulations care whether the numbers behave like independent uniform random numbers, and often care whether the numbers are reproducible at a later time. A Python example is `numpy.random.Generator`.

REFERENCES:

- Frauchiger, D., Renner, R., Troyer, M., "True randomness from realistic quantum devices", 2013.
- von Neumann, J., "Various techniques used in connection with random digits", 1951.
- Peres, Y., "[Iterating von Neumann's procedure for extracting random bits](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1176348543)", Annals of Statistics 1992,20,1, p. 590-597.